# Pages Library view to show pages that have been unpublished

Tags: sharepoint-online, view

We have a content expiry workflow in place which will automatically unpublish pages should they not be modified after a year.

Does anyone have a way of indicating in the pages library as to whether a page has been unpublished, as opposed to simply being a published page with a draft version.

Would be great to have a view showing these pages and then the site owner can elect to delete the pages or assign to a new content author for editing and republishing if still required.